# Force redraw of custom view (android)

Tags: android, canvas

I just have read similar questions but all answer don't work for me.

I have this custom view:

```
public class CompassTargetView extends View {

Context mContext;
Bitmap mBmp;

Matrix matrix;

int w, h, bw, bh;
int px = -1, py = -1;


public CompassTargetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);

    mContext = context;

    Resources res = getResources();
    mBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ttriangle);
    bw = mBmp.getWidth();
    bh = mBmp.getHeight();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(px == -1 && py == -1){
        px=w/2-bw/2;
        py=h/2-bh/2;
    }


    if (matrix != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBmp, matrix, null);
        matrix = null;
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBmp, px, py, null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    //registriamo le dimensioni della view
    w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}

public void setTrinagleIcon(){
    Resources res = getResources();
    mBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ttriangle);
    bw = mBmp.getWidth();
    bh = mBmp.getHeight();
    invalidate();
}

public void setCircleIcon(){
    Resources res = getResources();
    mBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.tcircle);
    bw = mBmp.getWidth();
    bh = mBmp.getHeight();
    invalidate();
}

public void setXY(Integer nx, Integer ny){
    px = nx - bw/2;
    py = ny - bh/2;
    invalidate();
}

public void translateIcon(Integer nx, Integer ny){
    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.postTranslate(nx, ny);
    invalidate();
}

public void rotateIcon(Integer nx, Integer ny, Float ang){
    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.postRotate(ang, nx, ny);
    invalidate();
}
```

}

it show a small icon then I want use setXY, translateIcon and rotateIcon to "animate" the icon. However the onDraw method is call only on view create after this if I call setXY, translateIcon and rotateIcon onDraw is not call.

I just use invalidate(); and I have try setWillNotDraw(false); but this don't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Displaying a Toast in the onDraw is a very bad idea since it may cause a call to onDraw which  will display the Toast and it will call onDraw.... infinite loop.

So replace the Toast by log (and keep the log only during debugging since onDraw is call very very often) and see what append.

---

The problem is that you are not updating the member matrix. You are creating a new one !

```
public void translateIcon(Integer nx, Integer ny){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  // <-- WRONG
    matrix = new Matrix(); // <-- CORRECT
    ...
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edit it (remove toast) but I get the same result.

Comment: @Martin ok. There is something strange in translateIcon and rotateIcon. see my edit

Comment: I have fix it but I have the same problem. I have problem also with setXY.

Comment: did you put a breakpoint in your onDraw method (just to confirm that is called only one time) ?

Comment: I have put a log message (Log.w(TAG, "canvas");) and this is call only one time.